# Java String.split() - NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string, numberformatexception

So, here's the thing, I've got this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine = br.readLine();
        String[] split = strLine.split(" ");

        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

let's say I have a file named **test.txt**, with just "**6 6**". So, it reads first line and splits that line into two strings. The problem is that I can use Integer.parseInt for the split[1], but I can't use that method for `split[0]` 
(`System.out.println(split[0])` prints "**6**"), which outputs me an error of:

```
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6"
```

UPDATE:
It might be problem of eclipse, because if I compile my .java files in terminal with javac, I don't get any exceptions!:))

UPDATE2: 
solved. something went wrong while saving with Kate. Don't know what, but gedit works better:D
Thank you all.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have invisible chars, like a BOM which could be the first char ? Print the size of your string.

Comment: TRUE. The length of split[0] is 2, so why does it print just "6"? how to remove those hidden characters?

Comment: It's probably a BOM. Open the file in a good text editor (not Notepad) and configure it to save the file without the BOM.

Comment: DataInputStream is for reading binary data. Don't use it if you're reading a text file.

Comment: So, what I got after hexdump -C test.txt is "|...2 6|". It's not BOM, because I save it with Kate with UTF-8 without BOM:/ (UPDATED:D)

Comment: "without UTF-8 " ? So what's exactly your encoding ?

Comment: My mistake. with UTF-8, without BOM;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with: hexdump -C test.txt if you have linux, you can see the non-printable chars you have.

Also the trim() answer it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem at the start of the file is usually due to a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which some software (mainly Notepad in fact) like to put at the start of Unicode files.

Open the file in a good text editor and configure it to save the files without the BOM.

If you can't change the file, skip the first char when reading it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following to rule out spurious/unexpected characters:

```
.. setup/read code in main method...
String[] split = strLine.split(" ");
for (String s : split) {
      System.out.println(String.format("[%s] => integer? %b", s, isInteger(s)));
}
... the rest of the main method....


private static boolean isInteger(String n) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(n);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you see anything inbetween the square brackets that isnt a number, or where the integer? returns false thats a likely the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to determine the actual encoding of the file you are reading, you can set it explicitly, so that any extra bytes are converted correctly into characters.

`new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...), <encoding>)`